# Puppeteer - clicks do not work outside of slowMo

Tags: puppeteer

I'm navigating with Puppeteer around a React website.

Two sample lines of code:

```
await page.waitForSelector('a.btn-lg[data-target="#loginModal"]');
await page.click('a.btn-lg[data-target="#loginModal"]');
```

With a sufficient slowMo value, the effects are consistent - the button gets clicked every time.
However, without slowMo, sometimes the button does get clicked, and sometimes it doesn't (a window wired to it doesn't open).

It happens for a lot of elements, not just this one button in particular.

I just started using Puppeteer, and it looks like I'm either misusing the library, or the website somehow screws up my efforts.

Please tell me why sometimes the effects of clicking are visible and sometimes not, and how to remedy it.

UPDATE:
Code such as this does not work either.

```
await page.evaluate(() => (document.querySelector('span.pum-close') as any).click());
await page.$$eval('span.pum-close', elements =>
        elements[0].click()
    );
```